# Working with UIScrollView and UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

In my project, I'm trying to do an app similar to Instagram where I can scroll endlessly on the images that I have inside my personal profile. While scrolling, the top portion of my profile details is above where the whole screen will be filled with my photos when continuously scrolling thru my photos.

I think the way to achieve this is using `UIViewController` and working with `UIScrollView` and `UICollectionView`. However, my issue here is how do I create a custom height of the `UICollectionView` or `UIScrollView` in order to show the proper or exact height of the `View`? As such, I do not want to see "white spaces" at the bottom, or "cut" pictures.

I've tried using `let height = CGRectGetHeight(self.myCollectionView)` to get the height, but it always return me with the height I fixed in my IB regardless the number of items I have.

Could someone share with me the structure how I should do it? Many thanks!

[image: d]